# Qt 5.7 black screen on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-studio-2013, qtwebengine

I have just upgraded my project to use Qt 5.7, on Mac I am able to load the html pages using Qt Webengine but on Window 7, the pages are not displayed, instead a black screen is shown.

I have also compiled simple browser example and it too only shows a black screen.

I am using the visual studio 2013 build of Qt 5.7

Does anyone know why it is not displaying the pages.

Does Qt 5.7 need any third party libraries for it render correctly on Windows.

Comment: Smells like broken GPU drivers. Can you try upgrading them?

Comment: checked my graphics card drivers and they are up to date

Comment: Which GPU do you have? What version of drivers?

Comment: NVIDIA version 10.18.13.6900, I tried installing an different windows 7 machine and I get the same problem

Comment: removing the graphics driver and reinstalling the driver fixes the problem. However as this problem occurs on every machine we install our software this solution cannot work for our users as they will not have the computer knowledge to do this.

Comment: As suspected, graphic drivers :\ Read carefully through https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers . Depending on the nature of the application, you might want/need to force ANGLE rendering, and/or ship a blacklist for the GPU drivers you find to be problematic.

Comment: Using Angle causes a crash in release and assert in Renderer9.cpp line 295.  Also after coming back to this after my holiday my machine is back to showing a black screen

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem, whenever we started an application with a QWebEngineView it would only show a black screen or even crash on another machine. The problems occured due to wrong versions of api-ms-*.dlls and d3dcompiler_47.dll we had packaged with our app.

We found the correct versions on our developer machine with installed Windows SDK under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist".

On a side note: We found that deployement of QWebEngine under windows is quite a hassle.. you also need to include "qtwebengine_locales" from qtbase\translations and "resources" from qtbase as well as "QtWebEngineProcess.exe" from qtbase\bin.

A thing that helped tracking down the problem, was putting "CONFIG += console" in the pro-file. That way the console output with relevant error information is shown on deployement targets.

Answer (score 1):

With help of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540943/qt-5-7-black-screen-on-windows/52556344#comment64568019_38540943) from [peppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873944/peppe)

One can use temporary workaround with graphic drivers not supporting DirectX11 but supporting DirectX9

As said here

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers

Graphics Drivers
For Qt Quick 2 to work, a graphics driver that provides OpenGL 2.1 or higher is required. The default driver from Windows is OpenGL 1.1. Qt includes a version of the ANGLE project which is included from the Windows Qt installers. ANGLE implements the OpenGL ES 2.0 API on top of DirectX 11 or DirectX 9. ANGLE requires that the DirectX SDK is installed when building Qt.

ANGLE chooses the render backend depending on availability. DirectX 11 is usually preferable. However, some graphics cards may not fully support it. For these cases, the environment variable QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM (introduced in Qt 5.4) can be used to control the render backend. Possible values are d3d11, d3d9 and warp.

So this may help

```
set QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM=d3d9
```

Or use mesa with

https://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html

Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL is special in the sense that it will try to load an OpenGL implementation with a non-standard name. The default name is opengl32sw.dll. This allows shipping a software-only OpenGL implementation, for example a build of Mesa with llvmpipe, under this name. If necessary, the filename can be overridden by setting the QT_OPENGL_DLL environment variable.

Edit 1:

One can use fallback method for one-time login to Dropbox Windows client ( made with QT framework ) for example

Dynamically Loading Graphics Drivers
In addition to the build time configuration, Qt supports choosing and loading the OpenGL implementation at runtime. To use this mode, pass -opengl dynamic to the configure script.

Note: As of Qt 5.5 this is the configuration used by the official, pre-built binary packages of Qt. It is strongly recommended to use it also in custom builds, especially for Qt binaries that are deployed alongside applications.

...

This configuration is the most flexible because no dependencies or assumptions are hardcoded about the OpenGL implementation during build time. It allows robust application deployment. When a given environment fails to provide a proper OpenGL 2.0 implementation, it will fall back automatically to ANGLE. This fallback will be completely transparent to the application, and will allow Qt Quick or other OpenGL code to function by translating to Direct3D. **Such a fallback could, for example, take place on a Windows 7 PC with no additional graphics drivers installed.** On other machines, where there is sufficient OpenGL support, the normal desktop OpenGL drivers will be used. Additionally, pure software-based OpenGL implementations may be available as additional fallbacks in the future, allowing running Qt Quick applications without a GPU.

When configured with -opengl dynamic, neither Qt nor the applications built using qmake will link to the opengl32 (standard desktop OpenGL) or QtANGLE libraries. Instead, the appropriate library is chosen at runtime. By default, Qt will determine whether the system's opengl32.dll provides OpenGL 2 functions. If these are present, opengl32.dll is used, otherwise the ANGLE libraries (libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll) will be used. In case the ANGLE libraries are missing or initialization fails for some reason, an additional fallback is attempted by trying to load opengl32sw.dll. See below for details.

> Such a fallback could, for example, take place on a Windows 7 PC with
>   no additional graphics drivers installed.

To emulate this conditions one can **use RDP session with mandatory 8 bpp to Windows machine**